Balls and Bins with uniform bin size limit
Suppose there are $n$ bins and $m$ balls, each bin can hold up to $k$ balls. $m<nk$. The balls are thrown into the bins that have less than $k$ balls one by one. At every throw, the probability of falling into each unfull bin is equal.
How to compute the expected number of bins with $i, 0\leq i\leq k$ balls in it?
Without the limit it is fairly easy, we can use a indicator variable for each bin and sum it up. The probability of having $i$ balls in a particular bin is straightforward.
But with the upper bound of $k$ it is less obvious how to compute this.

The expectation seems to be $\frac{m}{n}$ despite any upper bound on $k$. Is that something aligned to what you expected? If so, I will post some arguments.

Please provide your arguments. Many thanks.

This is a problem where the method of generating functions shows its strength.
Consider a generating function:
$$(1+s+s^2+...+s^k)^n= \sum_{m=0}^{kn}a(m,n,k)s^m$$
If m balls are randomly distributed among $n$ urns and the maximum number of balls in any urn can be $k$, then the number of different possibilities is given by $a(m,n,k)$.
Using a bit of algebra, we get the expression for $a(m,n,k)$:
$$a(m,n,k)= \sum_{i=0}^{[\frac{m}{k+1}]}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+m-i(k+1)-1}{n-1}$$
where $[x]$ denotes an integer part of $x$.
The probability that when m balls are randomly distributed among n urns, no more than k balls fall into any urn is therefore:
$$P(m,n,k)=\frac{a(m,n,k)}{n^m}$$
It's probably not exactly what you asked, but maybe it's a step towards a solution.

Andrew, I thought I could derive general expressions when I made my comment to your question earlier. Unfortunately, I couldn't. Just so that I don't disappear after making a cryptic comment, I am posting the following example as an answer:

The only interesting values for $k$ are $\left\lceil\frac{m}{n}\right\rceil \le k \le m$. Below the lower limit, there won't be space for all balls. Above the upper limit, there is lot of space and nothing changes.

I took an example $m=10$ balls. I worked out the probability distribution for your $0 \le i \le k$ for $n=1,2,...12$. I am just posting the distributions for $n=3$ and $n=4$.

The way I populated the distributions is by starting with integer partition of $m=10$ with maximum $n$ partions. You can see the partition table and the distributions for the interesting range of $k$ in the pictures below.

As you can verify, every distribution has an expected value of $\frac{m}{n}$. i.e. in this case, $\frac{10}{3}$ and $\frac{10}{4}$ respectively.




jfyi, I considered bins and balls as indistinguishable
